# Unwind array and match with other nodes using Cypher on Neo4j graph database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm creating an app using GRANDstack on top of a Neo4j graph database and I'm struggling with writing a query that unwinds a property array, matches some IDs, pullsback names associated with the IDs and repackages them into a new array.

Essentially, I have Memory nodes (Mems) and Person nodes (Person) and their relationship is as follows: (Mems)-[WITH]->(Person). i.e. you can have a memory of something where you were WITH multiple people. The Mems nodes contain a personID property that is an array of IDs and the relationship in the graph database is built from the array of personIDs in Mems nodes that match the personIDs in the Person nodes.

The result I'm trying to achieve is like the below, however I haven't found a way to return the nicknames from the Person nodes:

[image]

The query I'm using to generate the above is below:

```
MATCH (m:Mem)-[WITH]->(p:Person)
WHERE m.personID IS NOT NULL
UNWIND m.personID as personID
CALL {
    WITH personID
    MATCH (p:Person)
    WHERE personID = p.personID
    RETURN p.nickname
}
RETURN m.mem, m.date, personID, p.nickname
```

I think it's close to what I need but I just can't figure out the last bit where I can return the nicknames associated with the personIDs. This might be something that APOC is more capable of doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

This should work for you:

```
MATCH (m:Mem)-[:WITH]->(p:Person)
WHERE p.personID IN m.personID
RETURN m.mem, m.date, p.personID, p.nickname
```

Also, notice that the relationship pattern must use`:WITH` instead of `WITH` if you want to query for the `WITH` relationship type.

#### Addendum

Of course, since you have the `WITH` relationships, you should consider deleting the redundant `m.personID` property. You should get the same results without `m.personID` this way:

```
MATCH (m:Mem)-[:WITH]->(p:Person)
RETURN m.mem, m.date, p.personID, p.nickname
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. That's a much more elegant approach but unfortunately I'm still getting null values under p.nickname.

Comment: Return `p` to see what properties actually exist.

Comment: When I do that it's just the personIDs that exist but if I do a basic query that displays all Person nodes it displays all the Person node properties I’d expect

Comment: Then you need to figure out why not all `Person` nodes have the properties you expect. That is a totally different issue, and perhaps you need to create another question related to how you are creating the nodes.

Comment: Yes, you're right - when I'm creating the relationships I've just realised that I'm creating new nodes with just Person IDs instead of the relationship being linked to the existing nodes with the corresponding Person IDs. I've posted a new questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62802772/cypher-query-creating-new-nodes-instead-of-building-relationship-with-existing-n)

Comment: Do you know how I could consolidate all the p.nicknames back into an array for the individual m.mem nodes?

Comment: Sorry, on closer inspection this is returning the same nickname for all personIDs - the nickname for personID 1. So not quite working yet

Comment: See my updated answer. Note that it returns returns `p.personID` instead of `personID`, as we no longer need to use `UNWIND`.

Comment: This is brilliant, much simpler! Thank you so much again for all your help. Do you know how I could roll the nicknames back up into an array?