# Cypher query creating new nodes instead of building relationship with existing nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I currently have a query that builds a relationship between Men nodes and People nodes:

```
MATCH (m:Mem)
UNWIND m.personID as person
MERGE (p:Person{personID:person})
MERGE (m)-[:WITH]->(p)
```

The Mem nodes contain an array of PersonIDs that I am unwinding and then matching to the Person nodes with the corresponding PersonIDs. However, the query is building the relationship with ***new*** Person nodes that it creates, with just the corresponding personIDs property (and no other properties) instead of building the relationship with the ***existing*** Person nodes with the corresponding personIDs.

This is happening even though I have a unique constraint on the personID property for nodes with the Person label.

How can I write a query that build the relationships but doesn't create new nodes with the corresponding personIDs?

Comment: Since you are using `MERGE` (instead of `CREATE`) for the `Person` node, you would only be creating a new `Person` node if there is no node with the same `personID` value. You need to check why the expected `Person` nodes do not already exist.

Comment: Ok - I think I've worked it out. When I unwind the Mems property array the personIDs are **strings** but on the existing Person nodes the personIDs are **integers**, so when it does the merge it's creating new nodes with the corresponding personIDs as **strings** instead of creating the relationships with the existing nodes that have the personIDs as **integers**. So I need to work out how to set the values from the array as **integers** when they're unwound instead of leaving them as **strings**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the existing nodes store `personID` as an integer, you need to convert the `person` string values to integers via the `TOINTEGER()` function:

```
MATCH (m:Mem)
UNWIND m.personID as person
MERGE (p:Person {personID: TOINTEGER(person)})
MERGE (m)-[:WITH]->(p)
```